# A navigation problem: Is the path of the ship straight or curved?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, vectors, self-learning

My first post here: I’m looking for some guidance with a maths problem.

A ship sets sail from England (A) to France (B) covering a distance of 20 miles at an average speed of 5mph. If the ship sails in a straight line from A to B, the voyage should take ~ 4 hours in total.

The ship experiences a sideways current (lateral drift), perpendicular to *AB*, pushing it off course by 1 mile every hour on average. I’m trying to figure out if the ship’s shortest path will be straight or curved.

I’ve played with some sketches and calculations, showing the ship is best setting out for a destination offset from point B to counter the force of the current.

While one sketch shows a straight line, I’ve also noticed how the navigation problem relates to the Brachistochrone curve. However, I struggled to understand the underlying calculus.

Where can I look to figure out whether the ship’s path is curved or straight, expressed mathematically?

Any pointers appreciated!

Stephen

Comment: I don't know much about current. Do we assume the ship's drift of $1$mph is perpendicular to $AB$, regardless of the direction of motion of the ship? If so, I would have thought an offset straight line will get you to $B$ the quickest, although this is just my intuition.

Comment: Yes, I’m assuming perpendicular to _AB_

Comment: When you're dealing with a uniform field of current -- that is, it's the same $1$ mph drift in the same direction everywhere you go -- you can view the water as an inertial rest frame in which point B on the coast of France is traveling at $1$ mph. So you just need to intercept that moving point in that frame. The fastest intercept path in that frame will be straight, and this translates to a straight path in the original frame of reference where A and B are stationary.

Comment: All path in earth is curved but small arc of a circle of big radius seems to be a straight line segment.

Comment: I think you're looking for [radiodromes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodrome), which are a type of pursuit curve where a pursuer continuously changes its heading to catch a target. But as David K says, you can change your initial heading to compensate for the drift so you can get from A to B in a straight line. More about [pursuit curves](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html) here.

Comment: Thank you everyone!